# Change position of CalendarViewDayItem date number (TextBlock)

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to get this result using the UWP CalendarView
[image]
My biggest issue now is... How do I change the position of the "day number" text block that is created inside the `CalendarViewDayItem` ?

When using Visual Studio Live Visual Tree I can see that the `CalendarViewDayItem` has a `TextBlock` that represents the day number of the month, but I can't see how do I change it's `Vertical VerticalAlignment` to "Top" and `HorizontalAlignment` to "Left

Can anyone help ?

This is my actual result:
Trying to move the number inside de red circle to top and left of the box:
[image]

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DayColorBlock" TargetType="CalendarViewDayItem" >
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0.5"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0, 0, 0, 4"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarViewDayItem">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Red"  BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="20,20,20,20" Height="40" Width="40" Margin="20" />
                            <Rectangle Opacity=".6" Margin="0,0,0,10" MinHeight="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="DarkBlue" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">


        <CalendarView x:Name="calendarView" 
            Margin="12"
            CalendarViewDayItemChanging="CalendarView_OnCalendarViewDayItemChanging" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            CalendarViewDayItemStyle="{StaticResource DayColorBlock}">
        </CalendarView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough one! It seems that the `CalendarView` adds the day labels on top of the `CalendarViewDayItem`, next to your `Grid`. This is apparent in the XAML Live Tree viewer:

[image: The day TextBlock is next to the Grid]

To get hold of it, you will need to use the `CalendarViewDayItemChanging` and also implement a helper method to find the `TextBlock` in the `CalendarViewDayItem`.

`VisualTreeHelper` gives you the ability to walk the control tree and that includes the ability to get children of a given `DependencyObject`. We can then simply implement a helper method that will find the first direct child of a given type:

```cs
private T FindFirstChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject control) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
    for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < childrenCount; childIndex++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, childIndex);
        if ( child is T typedChild)
        {
            return typedChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now, armed with this method, we will get to our `TextBlock` and align it as we please!

```cs
private void CalendarView_OnCalendarViewDayItemChanging(
                CalendarView sender, 
                CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs args)
{
    var textBlock = FindFirstChildOfType<TextBlock>(args.Item);
    if (textBlock != null)
    {    
        textBlock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        textBlock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was driving me nuts.